# Type error Illegal invocation while click on search icon in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting an "illegal invocation" error in the console. When I click on the search icon

```
'focus' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.
```

Sometimes I get this error.

```
<div class="search-wrap">
  <input
    ref="searchInput"
    v-model="searchData"
    type="text"
    class="form-control search-input not-as-small"
    placeholder="Search by name"
    @input="inputSearchValue"
  >
    <i
      class="search-strong search-input-icon"
      @click.prevent="$refs.searchInput.focus"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: It should be `$refs.searchInput.focus()` ?

Comment: Thanks dude. Please post this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `$refs.searchInput.focus()` instead of It should be `$refs.searchInput.focus`

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    searchData: ''
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input
         ref="searchInput"
         v-model="searchData"
         type="text"
         class="form-control search-input not-as-small"
         placeholder="Search by name"
         >
  <button
     class="search-strong search-input-icon"
     @click.prevent="$refs.searchInput.focus()"
     >Focus on Input</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand why template didn't get the $refs.searchInput.focus. Why we need $refs.searchInput.focus() this one.

Comment: @smith correct method invoking convention is `focus()` not `focus`. Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Vue_refs_focus_management#vues_nexttick_method